# When a user registers on my python website, their first vote doesn't count

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, facebook-login

I have a voting website that uses Facebook login. When a user tries to vote, the website checks if a user is already in the database. If not, it asks them to log in to Facebook, adds them to the database, and then lets them cast a vote.

It works fine for users who are already in the system. But if a user is new, it successfully adds them to the database, but then doesn't add their vote. BUT if they then go to another page, they can vote just fine because they've already been added. I don't understand what's going on, since checking/adding users to the database and adding votes to the database are separate processes.

Here are the only places where the code treats new users and existing users differently (posting all the voting-related code would make this a super long post, but it doesn't distinguish between these types of users, so I'm thinking that's not where the problem is?)

**Javascript in HTML**

```
<script>
  var person = { userID: "", name: "", accessToken: "", picture: ""}
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1936452948301234',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v5.0'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status !== 'connected') {
            document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal();
        } else {
            addHiddenInput(response.authResponse.userID)
            person.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            person.userID = response.authResponse.userID;
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,picture.type(large)', function (userData) {
                console.log(userData);
                person.name = userData.name;
                person.picture = userData.picture.data.url;

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://mywebsite.com/fbuser',
                data: person,
                datatype: 'text',
                success: function myFunction(data) {
                console.log("fb data sent");
                }
                })

             });
        }

    });
  };

  function hideDialogAfterLogin () {
    document.getElementById("myDialog").close();
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        addHiddenInput(response.authResponse.userID)

    });
  }

  function addHiddenInput (userID) {
    var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("user_id")
    hiddenInput.value = userID
  }
</script>
```

LATER

```
<form action = "/insert_vote" method = "post" onsubmit="">
    <div id="vote-form" action = "/insert_vote" method = "post" onsubmit="">
        <div class="smalltext">
            {% for dict_item in vote_choices %}
                <input type="radio" name="options" padding="10px" margin="10px" id="{{ dict_item['id'] }}"
                value="{{ dict_item['id'] }}"> {{ dict_item['choice'] }} </input><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="mediumlefttext">
            Why did you make that choice?
        </div>
<!--        <input type="text"  name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="The article said only 10% of poodles are evil geniuses. It says it got its information from a new White House report, but when I got to www.whitehouse.gov, I find the report (www.whitehouse.gov/report.html), and it says 80% of poodles are evil." style="height:150px">  </input> <br>-->
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>


<!--<button onclick="javascript:login();" size="large" type="submit" value="Submit" scope="public_profile,email" returnscopes="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Submit</button>-->
        <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" style="display:none;">
        <Script>console.log("here comes the user id from the html");</Script>
        <Script>console.log(user_id);</Script>
        <input type="text" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="{{ article_id }}" style="display:none;">

<!--        <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" style="display:none;">-->
<!--        <input type="text" name="article_id" id="article_id" style="display:none;">-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </div>
</form>
```

**Python for users**

```
@application.route('/fbuser', methods=['POST'])
def fbuser():
    print("this is version 1.1")
    # global user_id
    # request.form is the data from facebook, includes userID, picture, name
    person = request.form
    print("FBUSER", person)
    print("ID", person.get("userID"))
    # user = person.get("userID")
    # we check the db for the user, if they exist we are done

    maybe_existing_user = User.query.filter_by(fb_id=person.get("userID")).first()

    # check if user is in db, if so, set ID...

    if(maybe_existing_user):
        fb_user_id = maybe_existing_user.id
        return "exists"
    else:
        new_user = User(int(person.get("userID")), person.get("picture"), person.get("name"), 5)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            print("success sql")
            now_existing_user = User.query.filter_by(fb_id=int(person.get("userID"))).first()
            # if(now_existing_user is None) Error
            fb_user_id = now_existing_user.id
            return "created"
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
            print(e)
            flash('Article url already exists, failed to post new user')
            print("sql fail")
            return "failed to create"
```

**Python for adding the vote**

```
@application.route('/insert_vote', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def insert_vote():
    posted = 1
    if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'GET':
        if not request.form['options']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            rate = 0  # rate of votes protection against no votes
            vote_choice_id = int(request.form['options'])
            comments = request.form['comments']
            article_id = int(request.form['article_id'])
            user_id = request.form['user_id']
            print(user_id)
            fb_user_id = int(user_id)
            av_obj = ArticleVote(fb_user_id, article_id, vote_choice_id, comments)
            db.session.add(av_obj)
            try:
                db.session.commit()
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
                print("user has already voted before")
                posted = 0

            if posted == 1:
                print("posted ==1 after")
                flash('Record was successfully added')
            else:
                db.session.rollback()

            a_obj = Article.query.filter_by(id=article_id).first()
            # this is the current global article
            avs_obj = retrieve_article_vote_summary(
                a_obj.id)  # vote_summary is a list of [tuples('True', numOfTrue), etc]
            total_votes = avs_obj.getTotalVotes()
            print("here's the object ", a_obj.id)
            print("this is the total votes ", total_votes)

            vote_choice_list = VoteChoice.getVoteChoiceList()
            vote_choices = []
            for item in vote_choice_list:  # looping over VoteChoice objects
                num = avs_obj.getVoteCount(item.choice)
                if total_votes > 0:
                    rate = num / total_votes
                vote_choices.append([item.choice, item.color, num, rate * 100, total_votes])

            print("a_obj", a_obj)
            details = avs_obj.getVoteDetails()  # 10/02 - retrieve array of tuples [(user, VoteChoice, Comments)]
            details_count = 0
            for detail in details:
                print(detail)
                details_count += 1
            return redirect('/results/' + str(a_obj.id))
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing the part of the code that adds their vote? There should be another piece of code for that (perhaps in the "myDialog" component?). If it's there, could you post it as well

Comment: Yeah, added --- it just references 'user_id', which it gets from a form. I'll add the form too.